# Windows phone SMS plugin with extra functions

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm using the code from this article, with phonegap app.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/glengordon/archive/2011/12/02/phonegap-on-wp7-tip-3-sending-sms-and-intro-to-plugins.aspx

The plugin works all fine, but when the SMS is sent, I want to return to my app automatically. Is this possible? If its possible to send an SMS without go to the default integrated sender, it could be even better.

I'm a newbie to C# and windows phone apps - please help me ;)

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to avoid the integrated SMS sender due to security reasons. User will return to your app after hitting the Back button on the SMS conversation page (that is esured automatically because of the stack-controlled nature of paging in WP7, but will not return after hitting the home button (again, this behavior cannot be prevented in any way) and your app will be suspended (possible to return to it by holding the back button and choosing it).